# Creating a space in SharePoint list column - by creating a syntax for the Dynamic Content combined within Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, flow, power-automate, column-formatting

I have created a Microsoft Form that has two separate questions 1. First Name  and 2. Last Name.

Then I created SharePoint list where it mirrored the answers on the form, after I created a Flow and within the flow put both questions 1 and 2 together within the list column 'Full Name' essentially combining them (at the point of the flow rather than combined formatting in two columns on the list).

But my problem now is both the First Name and Last show up on the list but there isn't a space between the two answers. I can't use the combined formatting as it's only one column, and I feel like this should be easy to fix but can't find the answers - maybe I'm not asking the right question?

I've added the two dynamic content fields into flow like such:
[image]

It then makes it's way into this column on the following SharePoint list but you will see the two dynamic content has been squished together.

[image]

I was seeing if there was a way to add some syntax or formatting in the flow but I'm not of a developer mind (I'm a designer).

Comment: Hi @Ana, You can add space in two responses from Power automate flow itself. Can you add a screenshot of how you are combining two responses & adding it to list column? Add screenshot by **editing** the original question. We will be able to help you more precisely by looking at current configuration of your flow.

Comment: Thank you for that, I have now added the images and exactly what fields I am trying to format :-)  - Ana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate multiple responses (string) from Power automate flow itself using **concat()** function.

**Syntax**:

```
concat('<text1>', '<text2>', ...)
```

**Example**:

```
concat('Hello', ' ' , 'World')
```

**Output**:

```
"Hello World"
```

**Documentation**: [concat function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#concat)

---

**Additional examples**: These are just examples to demonstrate how to use `concat` function in Power Automate flow.

1. [SharePoint join columns with a space between](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/SharePoint-join-columns-with-a-space-between/td-p/612935)
2. [MS Flow expression - how to concatenate New Line into string variable](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/MS-Flow-expression-how-to-concatenate-New-Line-into-string/td-p/286443)

Comment: How would that work when using Dynamic Content within Flow? 
I have added images to better illustrate. 

I can see the concat function but I'm not understanding the relationship.

Comment: In dynamic content --> expression popup, enter `concat(`, then select First Name from dynamic content options, add `, ' ' , ` --> again select Last Name from dynamic content & close the parenthesis `)`. Follow the syntax given in my answer.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried doing that:
concat(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r07e9ae1544af4eb8a4a64d51a1d43269'], ' ' ,outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/re7acfa8cac61415e9437597e1de4df93'])

But when I tested and looked at me list it doesn't show any data :-( 

I took a look at the test and it was successful and shows: 
"item/Title": "First Last",

Which is correct but on the sharepoint list, the column is showing blank but if you click into one item the name is being displayed in the edit screen? is there additional formatting needed for the column?

Comment: In the column formatting, 

In the box shows: 
=[First Name]&” “&[Last Name]

 and at the bottom of the box the warning says 'Please enter valid column-formatting JSON.'

Comment: If you do it from Power Automate flow, there is no need to change anything using JSON column formatting.

Comment: Thank you :-) 
I'm not sure why it was there in the first place but I removed it and it seems to work - just have an odd bug every once in a while and the whole column will show up blank oh well. 

Seems to be working now, thank you for your help and lesson!